# Right mouse button constantly clicking

Tags: mouse

My new Acer Laptop 7551 recently acquired a problem I can't find any information on.

The right mouse button almost constantly fires. I will be watching Youtube and that right button menu will appear. I hit escape and it will come right back. I get aggravated and click in a frenzy.
This will stop it for a few seconds and then it will start right up again.

The odd thing about this is that it happens whether or not the USB mouse is plugged in, whether or not I'm in Linux or Windows 7 (dual-boot system), whether or not the trackpad is disabled, just all the time.

I have installed the latest drivers found on Acer's website but no luck.
Of course, this started happening after the period in which Newegg would allow me to return it had passed.

Comment: To clarify: you have two mouse-like devices, a USB mouse and the built-in trackpad, and the problem occurs when either or both of those devices are disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go through Acer to get it looked at if Newegg won't take it back.  It's strange, but since the laptop is new, I'd suggest checking with Acer on service as this sounds like a hardware problem if it's happening on multiple OSes.

Comment: I'd say it's hardware as well.. software duplicating the problem on multiple OSes is highly unlikely.